# AdMob Banner wont show up, no error message with test ad and failed to load : 3 with real ad

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, admob

I have a Xamarin Forms application on which I would like to advertise via Admob. If I set my real ad-id, I get Ad failed to load : 3. When I use the id of a test-ad, there is no error message in the console, but there is also no ad.

Ive tried connecting with firebase, which [worked well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWE6y.jpg), but didn't fix the problem. Ive also changed the language of the app and specified in the google play console settings that my App uses ads (even through it isnt live yet).

I used a custom renderer:
Class in forms:

```
namespace test7
{
   
        public class AdMobView : View
        {
       
        }
    
}
```

android implementation:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AdMobView), typeof(AdMobViewRenderer))]
namespace test7.Droid
{
    public class AdMobViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<AdMobView, AdView>
    {
        public AdMobViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context) { }
        string id = "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxx/yyyyyyyyyy"; //here was my real id and test id
        private AdView CreateAdView()
        {
            var adView = new AdView(Context)
            {
                AdSize = AdSize.SmartBanner,
                AdUnitId = id,
                LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MatchParent, LayoutParams.MatchParent)
            };

            adView.LoadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().Build());

            return adView;
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<AdMobView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement != null && Control == null)
            {
                SetNativeControl(CreateAdView());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

xaml:

```
  <local:AdMobView x:Name="werbung" />
```

Any ideas how to fix this? Im lost :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MarcTron.Admob/) NuGet package. It sets everything up for you